# How can I increase the mouse cursor size?

Tags: mouse

How can I make the size of the mouse cursor bigger in Freya .3.1 ?? Any help would be appreciated. Just beyond a total noob. I do know that in Linux Mint Cinnamon this is easily doable but I don't like their UI. The guys at Elementary are doing an awesome job that is something new and unique. I am just a disabled musician living on disability, but I do plan on getting $20 to them in the next month or so. Totally worth it.

Comment: I have the same problem. My cursor is big outside Firefox, but very small inside (maybe size 10 or 12) in my 4K monitor. How to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install dconf Editor:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

After, run dconf Editor from applications menu, go to `org > gnome > desktop > interface`, find position "cursor-size" and input needed size of cursor, for example "36".

[image]

If cursor size suits for you, you needed to restart system from power menu.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did this on POP_OS the interface was in a different place but I got it