# elementary OS ignores manually set scaling factor

Tags: display, hidpi

I have set the scaling factor in the display settings as well as using dconf editor to '1', i.e. no scaling, but even after having rebooted a number of times the os still starts with 'pixel doubled' (2) scaling. Is there anywhere else I can disable this behaviour?

I suspect the reason for the automatic scaling is that my built-in screen is 4k@15.6". However, the setting is not set to automatic.

Comment: There are several issues at github [#138](https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-display/issues/138) and [#146](https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-display/pull/146).
Seems solution will be soon.

Comment: Try to set [`Gdk/WindowScalingFactor`](https://wiki.gnome.org/HowDoI/HiDpi). I've just done and that is working, but there is another issue - cursor is still double sized.

Comment: To fix cursor size read [this question](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2762/mouse-cursor-size)